# String replace with regex condition

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr, stringi

I have a pattern that I want to match and replace with an X. However, I only want the pattern to be replaced if the preceding character is either an A, B or not preceeded by any character (beginning of string).

I know how to replace patterns using the str_replace_all function but I don't know how I can add this additional condition. I use the following code:

```
library(stringr)

string <- "0000A0000B0000C0000D0000E0000A0000"
pattern <- c("XXXX")



replacement <- str_replace_all(string, pattern, paste0("XXXX"))
```

Result:

```
[1] "XXXXAXXXXBXXXXCXXXXDXXXXEXXXXAXXXX"
```

Desired result:

Replacement only when preceding charterer is A, B or no character:

```
[1] "XXXXAXXXXBXXXXC0000D0000E0000AXXXX"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("(^|[AB])0000", "\\1XXXX", string)
```

See the  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IgADvO/1)

**Details**

- `(^|[AB])` - Capturing group 1 (`\1`): start of string (`^`) or (`|`) `A` or `B` (`[AB]`)
- `0000`  - four zeros.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/cfiHJr):

```
string <- "0000A0000B0000C0000D0000E0000A0000"
pattern <- c("XXXX")
gsub("(^|[AB])0000", "\\1XXXX", string)
## -> [1] "XXXXAXXXXBXXXXC0000D0000E0000AXXXX"
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 In a TRE regex, `[\\^AB]` matches any of the 4 chars: ``\``, `^`, `A` or `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following. Using positive lookahead method here.

```
string <- "0000A0000B0000C0000D0000E0000A0000"
gsub(x = string, pattern = "(^|A|B)(?=0000)((?i)0000?)",
    replacement = "\\1xxxx", perl=TRUE)
```

Output will be as follows.

```
[1] "xxxxAxxxxBxxxxC0000D0000E0000Axxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew for the answer! It also works with the stringr package:

```
library(stringr)

string <- "0000A0000B0000C0000D0000E0000A0000"
pattern <- c("0000")

replace <- str_replace_all(string, paste0("(^|[AB])",pattern), "\\1XXXX")
replace

[1] "XXXXAXXXXBXXXXC0000D0000E0000AXXXX"
```